# Find Average response time of all urls present in Synthetic monitor of New Relic

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform, synthetic, nrql, newrelic-synthetics

I am having a Synthetic monitor for monitoring. I would like to write a query to find the average response time of all URLs present in my Synthetic monitor and create a  dashboard.
I can find the individual response time of the URL and create the dashboard.

can anyone help with the problem to get the average response time of all URLs and create a dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

When you say response time it sounds like you're looking for the receive duration? If you want to total duration of the request you can use `duration` instead of `durationReceive`.

Here's a basic NRQL query you can use for this.

FROM SyntheticRequest SELECT average(durationReceive) WHERE monitorName = 'Your monitor name' TIMESERIES since 1 week ago

If you want this to include all of your monitors just remove the where clause. Or if you want to only look at one URL you can do something like this.

FROM SyntheticRequest SELECT average(durationReceive) WHERE monitorName = 'your monitor name' and URL ='your URL' TIMESERIES since 1 week ago